# Failed Conversion with VMConverter 4.0.1

Tags: vmware-vcenter, vmware-converter

Received this error @ 57% on Windows Vista Enterprise SP1 conversion going to a VMWorkstation 6.5 image via network share.

```
  FAILED: A general system error occurred: SQL_CANTOPEN:
  unable to open database file
```

Running installed VMConverter 4.0.1-Build161434.

Anyone seen this error yet?

Comment: Added more tags.

Answer (score 3):

Please try to avoid the SMB share at first... Most errors in the middle of conversion come from network problems. If there are other problems with the source image, you'd have the error right at the beginning (< 5%) or at the end if there's a problem with the destination.

Copy the machine to the local disk and start the conversion again - it should work.

Comment: To make this answer useful: "unmount any SMB shares you have connected".